# Use of Ngfor in label mat-ltab

Tags: angular

I am facing a problem when using `*ngFor` in a `mat-tab` (included from angular material). I have a button that when clicked duplicates the code with `*ngFor`. My textArea inside this code has an `id = serReal{{j}}` where j is the index of the `*ngFor`. My reference is not working though. When I tried to get the element in my typescript code, it gets only the first one (`serReal0`). For the others I receive null.

My Html code:

```
    <!-- here I call it to duplicate -->
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="addData()" type="button" id="add_icon"></button>

    <!-- here it is my ngfor code which will duplicate -->
    <mat-tab-group>
          <mat-tab *ngFor="let itemServ of itemsServ; let j = index;" [label] = label[j]>
                <div class="areaTexto">
                      <div class="mdc-text-field text-field mdc-text-field--fullwidth mdc-text-field--textarea">
                            <textarea class="campoTextoServReal" 
id ="servReal{{j}}"></textarea>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>

    <!-- here I call it to read the text areas by the id -->
    <div class="divEncerraRel" id = apply>
          <button mat-raised-button (click) = 'setRelatorio()'>Encerrar Relatório</button>
    </div>
```

My TS code:

```
    itemsServ: number[] = [1];

addData() { 
  this.itemsServ.push(this.itemsServ.length + 1);
  this.label.push('Titulo');
}  

setRelatorio() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.itemsServ.length; i++) {
     console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("servReal" + i)));
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem is how you are setting your id in your html. Instead of

`<textarea class="campoTextoServReal" [id]="servReal{{j}}"></textarea>`

try

`<textarea class="campoTextoServReal" id="{{'servReal' + j }}"></textarea>`

Also, the reason why you are getting nulls when you are expecting the `<textarea id="servRealj">` (where j is the expected index) is because it is a tab group. When you are going between tabs, Angular removes the `mat-tab-body` from the DOM, so when you are searching for them by the element id, they don't exist. You can see this because when you go to tab 1 or tab 2, you will only see servReal1 and servReal2.

Answer (score 1):

By Binding the HtmlElements to back-end code you have access to them.
For this purpose angular prepared "ViewChild Property decorator".

In your HTML I added :

```
    <textarea #cmp class="campoTextoServReal" 
                       [id]="'servReal'+j"></textarea>
```

And in BackEnd component class define a variable:

```
  @ViewChildren('cmp') components:QueryList<HTMLInputElement>;
```

And for Logging

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.itemsServ.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.components._results[i].nativeElement.id);
     //console.log((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("servReal" + i)));
  }
```

link to stackbliz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-example-lkbkm8?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see is:

- Separate states tracking data `this.label & this.itemsServ`
- Querying the DOM to update the data

You should really start by defining your **domain or data structure** before working on rendering them.

For eg.

Define an interface that will hold your data structure

```
export interface Item {
  id: number;
  label: string;
  data: string;
}`
```

Then define a function to add:

```
addItem() { 
    const newIndex = this.items.length;
    const newItem = {
      id: newIndex,
      label: 'Titulo '+newIndex,
      data: 'data '+newIndex 
    } as Item

    this.items.push(newItem);
}
```

Define a function to update:

```
updateItem(id, data) {
    this.items.find((item) => item.id === id).data = data;
  }
```

Then you can start working on your template

To add call the addItem function above on button click

```
(click)="addItem()"
```

To update call your update function, for your situation you may want to update your data when your text-area change event gets triggered

```
(change)="updateItem(item.id, data.value)"
```

To render all tabs

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of items; let j = index;" [label]="item.label">
        <div class="mdc-text-field text-field mdc-text-field--fullwidth mdc-text-field--textarea">
            <textarea class="campoTextoServReal" 
                #data 
                [id]="item.id" 
                (change)="updateItem(item.id, data.value)">
                {{item.data}}
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Doing this may be more work but it eliminates you having to query the dom every time you want to update data.

You can find a complete example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdu2bg)